# Fire one ball at a time - Timing Issue Help - Cocos2d/Objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I am creating a iphone game currently using cocos2d. The basics of the game is that I have a cannon, and on pressing a fire button, the cannon fires a certain number of balls into the screen area.

So far, i have the layers setup with the cannon, the fire button, and even the balls. When I click the fire button, the cannon fires all the balls at the same time.

I have setup a for loop to loop through the ball objects in an NSMutableArray. For each one, I create it, add it to the layer, and then give it some motion. In theory, this should give me one ball at a time, however in testing it goes through the code so quickly that all the balls appear at the same time.

**What I need help with is the delay between firing consecutive balls i.e. fire a ball, wait 1 second, and fire next ball, so that it shows up on screen and thus the illusion of firing one ball at a time - if that makes sense.**

I have tried using the scheduler i.e. (ccTime) dt, but I don't need the delay to be repeating, if you know what I mean.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance. 
Pras.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fireball is function name

```
int ballcount; //.h file

//every 2seconds one ball will be inside ur fireball function check

[self schedule:@selector:(fireBall) interval:2];



 if(ballCount<8)
{   
    ballcount ++;    
}    
else
{
    [self unschedule: selector(fireBall)
}
```

Comment: Hi @Vijay, thanks for your response. But the problem is, say I have 8 balls, after firing 8 balls, this schedule will repeat?